# Create new sheet with google Apps Script and set name as 21-08

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, 2-digit-year

I am a newbie to google script. I need help to create a new sheet based on last sheet for e.g., last sheet name 21.07 (year and month) and then increment new sheet name to next month i.e 21.08

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please add your code in order for us to help you with the problem

Comment: Hi there, unfortunetly, I am learning very basic of script and don't have the code. I would appreciate if you could help me out.  Thanks

Comment: I see, if that is the case then unfortunately StackOverflow isnt really the correct choice as we are not really a tutorial provider or a free code writing service. I really recommend you to read the [How do i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [What questions are suitable?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section of Stackoverflow for tips and guidance on asking a good question in Stackoverflow